# CJSON Yiiframework Example

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to learn the Yii Framework to work on a project called HumHub, however the documentation is lacking in examples and I am very, very new to frameworks in general. Usually I am developing my own per my unusually OCD mind.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON

How would I use the CJSON class to read a json file and utilize it as vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can decode javascript text into php variable like this, but first you have to read the file into text like :

```
 $json_text = file_get_contents('file.json');
 // or the yii way
 $json_text = $this->renderPartial('path.to.file.json', null, true, true);

 // then decode it 
 $var = json_decode($json_text);
 // or the yii way
 $var = CJSON::decode($json_text);
```

Comment: Is the path the module path or the full path? In the Yii way? I also read there is a `renderJSON()` function, but again no examples.

Comment: use `application.modules.YOUR_MODULE.foldername.file` or whatever your path to file is

Comment: Thanks, can you see the edit I made to my comment? Nevermind that is for rendering a JSON file.